# How to use KNeighborsClassifier using a precomputed distance matrix?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, classification, knn

I need to use the `KNeighborsClassifier` class from `scikit-learn` to classify a data set. In the [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) it says that you can use a precomputed distance matrix but I have tried it and it gives me an error with the dimensions of the matrix that I pass as a parameter. After several tests I managed to get no error. This is my code:

```
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

X_train = [[0, 0], [1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
y_train = [0, 0, 1, 1]
X_test = [[1, 2], [1,3]]

# Precomputed matrix of distances between training instances
distances_traint = pairwise_distances(X_train)
print(distances)

# Precomputed matrix of distances between test instances and training instances
distances_test = pairwise_distances(X_test, X_train)
print(distances1)

# Create a KNN classifier using the precomputed metric
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3, metric='precomputed')

# Train the classifier using the training dataset and labels
knn.fit(distances_train, y_train)

# Predict the class for the test instance using the precomputed matrix of distances
prediction = knn.predict(distances_test)

# print prediction
print(prediction)
```

The output is this:

```
[[0.         1.41421356 2.82842712 4.24264069]
 [1.41421356 0.         1.41421356 2.82842712]
 [2.82842712 1.41421356 0.         1.41421356]
 [4.24264069 2.82842712 1.41421356 0.        ]]
[[2.23606798 1.         1.         2.23606798]
 [3.16227766 2.         1.41421356 2.        ]]
[0 1]
```

I believe that the output is correct, but I have my doubts about the implementation that I have used. I wonder why it is necessary to pass to the `fit` method the `distances_train` matrix of distance between the elements of `X_train` if what it actually uses in the `predict` method to make the prediction is the `distances_test` matrix of distance between the elements of `X_test` and `X_train`.

On the other hand, this is just an example. In practice I would have a data set that is partitioned into train and test randomly and the distance matrix between all the elements of the data set. Therefore, I would have to look in my distance matrix for the submatrix corresponding to the set of train to pass as a parameter to the `fit` method and the submatrix corresponding to the distances between test and train to pass as a parameter to the `predict` method.

If someone can give me an opinion on this I will be grateful.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why it is necessary to pass to the fit method the distances_train matrix of distance between the elements of X_train.

- For not-precomputed:
  You want to do a classification. The model needs to know which classes are present **and 'where' they are**.
  This happens during the fit, here you need information about the position and the classes `y_train`.
- For precomputed:
  For example one can look at your first `x_test[0] -> [2.236 1. 1. 2.236]`.
  The model will select the `k=3` nearest neighbors, that will be `x_train[[0,1,2]]` with the classes  from `y_train[[0,1,2]] -> 0,0,1` and therefor class 0.

At this point **you are correct to ask, why does this need x_train in your case? You're right it does not, but** there are is at least one other functionality.
For example you can decide which points are allowed to be connected (i.e. your data is a graph).

> If metric is “precomputed”, X is assumed to be a distance matrix and must be square during fit. **X may be a sparse graph, in which case only “nonzero” elements may be considered neighbors.**

As long as you do not interpret your data as a graph and/or call `knn.kneighbors|_graph` without arguments, I do not see that the usage of a correct `x_train_distance` is necessary for inference.

Beside this I think this is mostly an interface thing and how checks are performed for classifiers in general, i.e. `len(X) == len(Y)`.

Comment: From what I understand from your answer, I am using the precomputed distance matrices correctly in the use of the `KNeighborsClassifier` class. I also interpret that to use my distance matrix of all the instances I will have to know which ones are going to train and test and take the respective distance submatrices to pass to `fit` and `predict`.

Answer (score 1):

> I wonder why it is necessary to pass to the `fit` method the `distances_train` matrix of distance between the elements of `X_train` [...]

The `precomputed` distance matrix is just another way of specifying the neighborhood of each points; actually it's *all* that the model needs to know about them as long as you don't need it to predict based on coordinates. Under the hood, a distance matrix is created in any case because that's what lets the model determine which other points are closest to any given point (under the respective metric) and also what lets it weigh their closeness when `weights="distance"`.

> [...] if what it actually uses in the `predict` method to make the prediction is the `distances_test` matrix of distance between the elements of `X_test` and `X_train`.

This is the equivalent of passing coordinates to a model that has been trained on coordinates. In the present case, the fitted model "thinks" in distances to the training points it has seen before.

> Therefore, I would have to look in my distance matrix for the submatrix corresponding to the set of train to pass as a parameter to the `fit` method and the submatrix corresponding to the distances between test and train to pass as a parameter to the `predict` method.

That's perfectly right and straightforward to do: `train_test_split` takes any number of arrays as the first argument so if you have just the distance matrix, you split its index and construct the two sub-matrices from there. The example below shows the exact equivalence between training on coordinates and on a distance matrix using the same `metric`.

```py
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split, GridSearchCV, KFold, cross_val_score
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import pairwise_distances

n_samples = 1000
n_neighbors = 3
metric = "cosine"

X, y = make_classification(n_samples=n_samples, random_state=42)

index = np.arange(n_samples)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test, train_ix, test_ix = train_test_split(X, y, index, random_state=42)
knn = KNeighborsClassifier(metric=metric, n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
knn.fit(X_train, y_train)

D = pairwise_distances(X, metric=metric) # (n_samples, n_samples) square matrix
# the fitted model "thinks" in distances to the training points, 
# so what is discarded is distances *to the test points*, if you will
D = D[:, train_ix]
D_train, D_test = D[train_ix], D[test_ix]
knn_dist = KNeighborsClassifier(metric="precomputed", n_neighbors=n_neighbors)
knn_dist.fit(D_train, y_train)

assert knn.score(X_test, y_test) == knn_dist.score(D_test, y_test), "Scores are not equal"
```